# invalid query or character type

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

looking for some help with a query

I am currently attempting to do this:

```
    $query_set_character_to_trademark = "
    UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, 'â"¢', '™')";
```

with a php script

Using this on the mysql command line works perfectly:

```
    UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, 'â"¢', '™')
```

My issue is that the query in my script shows a syntax error on the characters. My problem is that these characters are imported and exist on my database all over the place and I need to change them in the name column every day.

help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Escape the double quote in the string. Like so:

```
$query_set_character_to_trademark = "
    UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, 'â\"¢', '™')";
```

If you do not do that php is confused where does the string end.

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo, it worked perfectly. This will still look for the 3 characters in the string right?

Comment: if I need to replace a bottom quote with a top quote I would do the same? (name, '„', '\"')

Comment: Yes. So each time you have a double quote in a string enclosed in double quotes you need to escape that symbol so that it is clear where the string ends.